# Finding the nearest power of 2 with a formula

Tags: number-theory

Is there any simple formula that can be used to find the nearest power of 2 of a number?

So, let's say I got the number $15$, it has to give $16$, If I got the number $55$, it gives me $64$, etc.

Comment: Nearest in what sense?  is $12$ "nearer" to $8$ or is it "nearer" to $16$?  What about $11.5$?  Whatever your final interpretation, play with $\log_2$ and floor/ceiling functions.

Comment: indeed, if it is the same distance to two power of 2's, it can use any of the two. I was wondering if their is a closed form formula, without using floor/ceiling functions...

Comment: Given the very nature of what you are describing as being a step function of sorts... a floor or ceiling is almost guaranteed in some form.

Comment: If you convert you number into binary, you can easily do this

Comment: @Steven31415 In Excel, you are better off using `POWER(2, ROUND(LOG(X,2)), 0)` since the `LOG()` function takes an optional base argument, and you seem to be interested in nearest power, so `ROUND()` is a better fit that `ROUNDUP()`

Comment: @Steven31415 Not true.  That would make $2^{n+1/2}$ the dividing line between $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$, but it should be $3 \cdot 2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting integer into binary can produce a simple Excel formula:
**POWER(2,LEN(DEC2BIN(your cell)))**

Answer (score 1):

$a=\log_2 x- \lfloor \log_2 x \rfloor$

$b=\lceil \log_2 x \rceil -\log_2 x$

If $min\{a,b\}=a$ then the nearest power of $2$ is $2^{\lfloor \log_2 x \rfloor}$,

Else it is $2^{\lceil \log_2 x \rceil }$